# Two click events in reverse order

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a table cell with an alert in a click event like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="cid" onclick="alert('I want to run 2nd!')">Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Later I want to add a new alert on the event handler (click) of the same element with jquery like this:

```
<script>
$('#cid').on('click',function() { alert('I want to run 1st!'); });
</script>
```

When I run the code I get 2 alerts (as expected) but not with the wanted order. The second alert should appear first and the first second.
The final td I want is:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="cid" onclick="alert('I want to run 1st!');alert('I want to run 2nd!')">Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried to implement this code (from other posts):

```
<script>
var clcks = $('#cid').data('events').click.slice();
var cid = $('#cid').unbind('click');
$.each(clcks.reverse(), function() { cid.click(this); });    
</script>
```

but the result is the same.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using the onclick attribute.

Comment: Can you be more specific! I am using the onclick attribute but what's that mean?

Answer (score 0):

The event registration takes preference of the inline declared events over the external (unobtrusive) events. So in your case `onclick="alert('I want to run 2nd!')` is executed first and then `$('#cid').on('click',function() { alert('I want to run 1st!');`
If you want to achieve it as per your requirements, you need to create a single function and call the alerts as per your preference, either using the first or second approach, not both. Also, as a good practice, try to avoid inline events. Your becomes comparatively faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: Your suggestion is not working. Furthermore .stopPropagation() will stop the existent onclick event and this sth I don't want!

Comment: As I said, I don't have access to change the inline event. So, I need to find a way to capture it before it is fired, put in a function, add first the event I want and then fire the existent one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- HTML-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id='button' style='width:40px;height:40px;background-color:red;'></div>
    </body>

    </html>

// JS
$(function(){        
    $("#button").bind('click',first);
    $("#button").bind('click',second);
    $("#button").bind('click',third);

    var clicks = $('#button').data('events').click.slice();
    var button = $('#button').unbind('click');
    $.each(clicks.reverse(), function() {
        button.click(this);
    });    
});

function first() { alert("first"); };
function second() { alert("second"); };
function third() { alert("third"); };
```

Comment: This code creates three onclick events with jquery and handles them. My first onclick event is an attribute in the td element and for some reason that I don't know this code is not working!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use data and jQuery when doing this to support an unlimited number of elements.  Additionally, make sure your `td` is inside a `tr` and `table`, because it won't run properly without those two containers.

```js
$("#cid").click(function () {
  $("#cid").unbind("click").attr("onclick","").click(function () {
    console.log('I want to run 2nd!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td id="cid" onclick="console.log('I want to run 1st!')">Test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Again the same.... the alert('I want to run 2nd!') already exists in td element. Only the alert('I want to run 1st!') is created with jquery and this is how it should remain. And the td element is inside a tr and a table elements.

Comment: @Panos Updated, if you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: It is not working as I want. I want with just ONE click to fire the created alert and then fire the inline alert.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to figure it out!
The following code does exactly what I want:

```
<table><tr></tr><td id="cid" onclick="alert('I want to run 2nd!')">Test</td></tr></table>
<script>
document.getElementById("cid").setAttribute("onclick","alert('I want to run 1st!');"+document.getElementById('cid').getAttribute('onclick'));
</script>
```

Hope it helps.